# XSLT transform xml string inside node to xml node tree

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML file, where the content of the XML node is another XML document in a string.

```
<Response>
  <XML>
    &lt;Ping&gt;
       &lt;Success /&gt;
       &lt;EchoData&gt;Hi, this is a ping!&lt;/EchoData&gt;
    &lt;/Ping&gt;
  </XML>
</Response>
```

I need the output of this to be like the XML below, using XSLT, but I'm not sure how I can solve this.
I have tried some replace functions, but with no luck.

This is the result I'm trying to get:

```
<Ping>
  <Success />
  <EchoData>Hi, this is a ping!</EchoData>
</Ping>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible natively in XSLT 3.0 and possible with processor-specific extension functions on some 1.0 and 2.0 processors. Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Or you could explore `disable-output-escaping` if your processor supports that.

Comment: Thanks Ian, disable-output-escaping did the trick! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Ian suggested, I solved this by adding `disable-output-escaping` to the `value-of`.

My transformation now looks like this, and gives me the result I want.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/Response">
      <xsl:value-of select="XML" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You just need to be careful with disable-output-escaping that it only works if your transformation generates serialized output - you can't reuse the transformation as part of a pipeline, or send the output to a DOM tree, for example.